# Duvidas de como consumir ws NfS-e Curitiba

Tags: java, xml, nfe

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Agora seguinte meu retorno so vem assim

```
<EnviarLoteRpsResposta xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <NumeroLote xsi:nil="true" />
  <DataRecebimento xsi:nil="true" />
  <ListaMensagemRetorno>
    <MensagemRetorno>
      <Codigo>E504</Codigo>
      <Mensagem>O certificado digital do prestador de serviços é obrigatório.</Mensagem>
      <Correcao>Envie junto a requisição do serviço o certificado digital do prestador de serviços.</Correcao>
    </MensagemRetorno>
  </ListaMensagemRetorno>
</EnviarLoteRpsResposta>
```

Segue minha autenticação

```
  public void chamadaWs(String xml) {
        URL wsdlURL = WSX0020X0020NFSEX0020V1001.WSX0020X0020NFSEX0020V1001_WSDL_LOCATION;
        QName WSX0020X0020NFSEX0020V1001_QNAME = new QName("http://www.e-governeapps2.com.br/", "WS_x0020_-_x0020_NFS-e_x0020_V1.0.0.1");
        WSX0020X0020NFSEX0020V1001 ss = new WSX0020X0020NFSEX0020V1001(wsdlURL, WSX0020X0020NFSEX0020V1001_QNAME);
        WSX0020X0020NFSEX0020V1001Soap port = ss.getWSX0020X0020NFSEX0020V1001Soap();

        String retorno = port.recepcionarXml("RecepcionarLoteRps", xml);

        System.out.println("recepcionarLoteRps.result=" + retorno);
    }

    private void autentica() {
        String caminhoDoCertificadoDoCliente = "C:\\Nf-se\\certificado.pfx";
        String senhaDoCertificadoDoCliente = "123456";
        String caminhoDoKeyStore = "C:\\Nf-se\\cacerts";
        String senhaDoKeyStore = "123456";

        System.setProperty("java.protocol.handler.pkgs", "com.sun.net.ssl.internal.www.protocol");
        Security.addProvider(new com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider());
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType", "PKCS12");
        System.clearProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore");
        System.clearProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword");
        System.clearProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", caminhoDoCertificadoDoCliente);
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", senhaDoCertificadoDoCliente);
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType", "JKS");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", caminhoDoKeyStore);

    }
```

Comment: como começar. 
https://www.google.com.br/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=how%20to%20consume%20a%20wsdl%20in%20java

Comment: na vdd eu so preciso executar um metodo desse ws que seria o 
RecepcionarXml, onde eu passo o nome do metodo e o xml !!!!

Comment: Eu tenho uma solução para envio, mas é em C#. Ajuda?

Comment: ajuda se puder mandar

Comment: Olha, estou reparando que suas edições estão mudando completamente a duvida inicial, e não é correto fazer isso. Se a solução abaixo resultou outra duvida, deve-se abrir uma nova pergunta, não alterar a recente, senão você invalida as resposta já dadas.

Comment: na vdd a duvida continua a mesma , porem com situacoes diferente , mas o problema ainda nao mudou , por isso a alteracao

Comment: Tem muito screenshot e pouca clareza no problema . A mensagem é já diz que você não está usando certificado digital, mas não tem como sabermos onde você está "enroscado". Seria o caso de ou explicar a dificuldade que está tendo com o certificado ou com o código. Mas provavelmente vai ter que abrir uma pergunta sobre o problema exato. (não adianta abrir outra genérica, tem que ser uma específica sobre o problema e não sobre a mensagem de erro, que já foi mais do que discutida aqui). Aqui tem umas dicas: [ask]

Answer (score 2):

A Prefeitura de Curitiba já foi minha cliente. Normalmente, os *Web Services* deles são feitos em C#, cuja documentação pode ser facilmente acessível através do endereço:

> https://isscuritiba.curitiba.pr.gov.br/Iss.NfseWebService/nfsews.asmx

No caso, o método que você precisa chamar é o `RecepcionarXml`, que está aqui:

> https://isscuritiba.curitiba.pr.gov.br/Iss.NfseWebService/nfsews.asmx?op=RecepcionarXml

A melhor forma de testar isso manualmente é usando uma ferramenta como o [SoapUI](https://www.soapui.org/). Basta usar este WSDL dentro de uma requisição do SoapUI que a aplicação monta o XML da requisição pra você. Você terá que colar manualmente o XML dentro do formulário da requisição para conseguir enviar. [Aqui tem um tutorial](https://www.soapui.org/getting-started/your-first-soapui-project.html).

Feito isso, basta [consumir o Web Service](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=consumir+web+service+%5Bjava%5D).

Comment: Amigo me ajuda vou postar o erro alii

Comment: Amigos agora estou com outro erro , vou postar tentem me ajudar

Answer (score 0):

A conexão é HTTPS logo você precisa ter o certificado digital tipo A1/A4 para acessar o wsdl, ou criar um certificado fake no site deles para o servidor piloto, tem isso nos [manuais](https://isscuritiba.curitiba.pr.gov.br/portalnfse/manuais.aspx).

Só que se usar o certificado piloto acredito que terá limitações para consumo, então o melhor seria um certificado verdadeiro mesmo.

http://pilotoisscuritiba.curitiba.pr.gov.br:8080/certsrv/

HTTPS:

Precisa gerar um arquivo cacerts com as chaves, da para fazer com a ferramenta keytool do Java ou usar aquela classe InstallCert.java que tem inúmeras versões por ai, inclusive no meu [gist](https://gist.github.com/dilnei/86f19fe2261589c21303).

neste ponto você adiciona as url's https, quantas precisar conforme aumentar o número de prefeituras.

> get("isscuritiba.curitiba.pr.gov.br", 443, ks);

Quanto ao certificado utilizando o piloto ou um certificado original nada vai acontecer se não vincular o mesmo no sistema deles, e para isso um cadastro junto a prefeitura é necessário.

No passado quando desenvolvi perdi muito tempo tentando fazer isso funcionar depois acabei descobrindo que só era possível fazer pelo browser I.E(não sei se ainda é assim).

Depois que estas etapas estiverem prontas você vai conseguir testar com SoapUI e também gerar seus stubs Java para utilizar no código a invocação a esses serviços, mas você precisa ler os manuais, tem tudo lá.

Propriedades:

```
 public static void AssinaSSL(String caminhoCertificado, String senhaCertificado) {
        System.setProperty("sun.security.ssl.allowUnsafeRenegotiation", "true");
        System.clearProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore");
        System.clearProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword");
        System.clearProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore");
        Security.addProvider(new com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider());
        System.setProperty("java.protocol.handler.pkgs", "com.sun.net.ssl.internal.www.protocol");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType", "PKCS12");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", caminhoCertificado);
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", senhaCertificado);
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType", "JKS");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "/nfse/certificados/cacerts");
    }
```